# ClientID getting changed when deploying asp.net 2.0 website to Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, clientid

I have a website which is hosted on GoDaddy they have version 4.0 runtime. 
The issue is the client id of the server controls are generated as "contentPlaceHolder1_drpBanks" where it was earlier (when the website was on some other server) getting generated as "ctl00_contentPlaceHolder1_drpBanks".

What I need to know is there a way to resolve this so that I don't have to make any changes in the code.

Like a setting in web.config file or something.

Comment: You learnt a valuable lesson, do not rely on auto-generated names. There are much better ways to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future use `<%=Control.ClientID%>` which will successfully resolve every time - without code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Controls in ASP.NET 4.0 have a [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property. If you set this to [`AutoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx), ASP.NET should generate client ids in the same way it did in ASP.NET 2.0. Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) that explains the different client id modes.

Besides setting `ClientIDMode` at the control level, you can also set it at the page or application level:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode ="AutoID" ... %>
```

or

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="AutoID" />
</system.web>
```

But I agree with leppie's comment that it is dangerous to rely on generated client ids.

Comment: Sure I will take care next time onwards. Thanks alot

Comment: Future readers: note that *ClientIDMode* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx and *article* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx do not contain the same info.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this functionality in ASP.NET2.0? I mean ClientIDCode="Static" functionality in 2.0.(for predefined ID's in web application, this should not be change otherwise it will effect other places.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. There is just one id generation algorithm in ASP.NET 2.0. This wasn't a problem at the time because there wasn't a lot of client-side code back then.